# Realm's setDefaultRealmSchemaVersion isn't executed

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to migrate a Realm and assign a property to be a primary key - but `setDefaultRealmSchemaVersion` seems like its not being executed:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {

    // prints "Current Version: 3"
    println("Current version \(schemaVersionAtPath(Realm.defaultPath, encryptionKey: nil, error: nil)!)")

    let migrationBlock: MigrationBlock = { migration, oldSchemaVersion in

        if oldSchemaVersion < 4 {

            migration.enumerate(Fruits.className()) {oldObject, newObject in
                    let id = oldObject!["id"] as! Int
                    newObject!["primaryKeyProperty"] = id
            }
        }
        println("Migration complete")
    }

    setDefaultRealmSchemaVersion(4, migrationBlock)

    // prints "New Version: 3"
    println("New Version: \(schemaVersionAtPath(Realm.defaultPath, encryptionKey: nil, error: nil)!)")  
}
```

Any ideas why is that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your `Realm`'s migration block will only be executed if you explicitly migrate the Realm, or create the Realm via `Realm()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't quite get how to "explicitly migrate the Realm" - what isn't explicit about the migration in the above code?

Comment: You haven't explicitly called `public func migrateRealm(path: String, encryptionKey: NSData? = nil) -> NSError?` to actually perform the migration.